# $A$ is a square complex matrix. $A^k-A=0$ for some $k\geq 2$. Prove that $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

$p(x)=x^k-x=x(x^{k-1}-1)$

What I want to do is to say that $(x^{k-1}-1)=(x-z_1)(x-z_2)...(x-z_{k-1})$ and therefore A is diagonalizable (because of the distinct roots in the polynomial), but i'm not sure that I don't get repeated roots here.

I know in general that there are $n$ different complex solutions for $z^n=r$ when $z$ is different than zero, but is it also true for when $r=1$?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have repeated roots since they are the $(k-1)^{th}$ roots of unit. So you have $k$ distinct eigenvalues, then $A$ is diagonalizabile over $\Bbb C$. Moreover if $k=2,3$ $A$ is diagionalizable over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: But how can I get so many different solutions for $z^k=1$? I can think of $1,-1,i,-i$ and that's it. what other solutions are there for example for $z^8=1$?

Comment: write $z^k=e^{2\pi i}$, then the solution are given by $z_m=e^\frac{2m\pi i}{k}$ for $0\le m\le k-1$. Observe that $z^k_m=e^{2m\pi i}=e^{2\pi i}=1$. After that you can write $z_m$ in polar coordinates and you have done.

Comment: I don't know the formula you used. All I know is that if $z=rcis\theta$ than $z^n=r^ncis(n\theta)$ and I'm not even sure how to use that in order to solve $z^n=1$. Can you try to explain it in a different way?

Comment: That's the same. The only different is that you write $z$ in polar coordinates. Set $z_m=cis(\frac{2\pi mi}{k})$, in this case $r=1$, and what happens when you do $z_m^k$.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure what you mean by $z_m$. Do you mean "the m-th root"?

Comment: You have $k$ roots and $m$ count them